# C# how to add new text in Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I want to add new text in next row. How do i add to not delate old text? I select row in combobox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Excel.Application x0 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook x1;
        Excel.Worksheet x2;

        x1 = x0.Workbooks.Add();
        x2 = x1.ActiveSheet;
        x2.Name = "Dane";

        int a = Convert.ToInt16(comboBox1.Text);
            x2.Cells[a, 1] = textBox1.Text;
            x2.Cells[a, 2] = textBox2.Text;
            x2.Cells[a, 3] = textBox3.Text;
            x2.Cells[a, 4] = textBox4.Text;

        x0.DisplayAlerts = false;
        x1.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\save to excel", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        x1.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
```

Comment: if a is your row number then the next row is a+1. x2.Cells[a+1, 1].Value = "myText";. However I recommend to you EPPLUS more easier and does not depend on Excel lib.s: http://epplus.codeplex.com/. If you want an example. I can provide one.

Comment: @BassemAkl Akl i learn programming and my teacher asked this task. I need to do in Visual Studio. I dont want to overwrite this file, just add text on selected in combobox row. I dont know how i do this because when i add next row and send apply old text disappears.